# How to find number of occurrences of a substring in a string given starting point and ending point?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, substring

Given a string and a substring, as well as the index of starting point and ending point, I want to be able to find the number of occurrences of that substring in the bound. For example, given the string "ACACTACG", and I want to find the number of occurrences of the substring "AC" from 3 to 7 (if the first index is 1). The above example produces the output 2. From 3 to 7, we have "ACTAC" in which the substring "AC" occurs 2 times. I can't seem to code this out in C++;

This is problem C of AtCoder Beginner Contest 122: https://atcoder.jp/contests/abc122/tasks/abc122_c

I ACTUALLY MANAGED TO CODE THIS OUT but the time limit is exceeded. I need a simpler approach to this.

Here's my submission for the TLE result:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int N, Q;
    string s;
    cin >> N >> Q >> s;

    for(int i = 0; i < Q; i++)
    {
        int l, r;
        cin >> l >> r;
        if(l >= r)
        {
            cout << 0 << endl;
            break;
        }
        int count = 0;
        for(int j = l - 1; j < r; j++)
        {
            if(s[j] == 'A' && s[j + 1] == 'C' && j != r - 1)
            {
                count++;
                j++;
            }
        }
        cout << count << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

After doing some maths, I managed to discover that the reason I got TLE is because my code has roughly 10^10 instructions while the 2 seconds time limit is only capable of executing about 2 * 10^8 instructions.

Comment: If you're 100% certain that the code work flawlessly otherwise, then what you seem to want is a code-review which should be posted on https://codereview.stackexchange.com. But please make sure are [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) there first.

Comment: Please give your variables meaningful names, that makes it much easier to read and understand your code, and also lowers the risk of hard to detect bugs, e.g. caused by copypaste errors, spelling mistakes or simple oversight due to things like `l`, `I` and `1` looking similar. `int numberOfFoobars;` is much better than `int N;`.

Comment: My bad. Sorry about those mistakes. This is my first time asking questions like this hahah

Answer (score 2):

The string N is the same for all queries, and you're only looking for the pattern `AC`. This means you can precompute a lookup table for the answers and avoid iterating though N for every query.

The lookup table would have the number of occurrences of `AC` since the beginning of the string. For ACACTACG it would be

```
A={0,1,1,2,2,2,3,3}
```

This helps because "the number of occurrences of AC between x and y" is the same as "the number of occurrences before y, except those that are before x". Tables like this are generally useful whenever you have to answer questions about ranges

For example, to answer the query 3,7 you compute A[7]-A[3] = 3-1 = 2.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

As **Joni** said, you can create a lookupArr like **arr**. Since the pattern to match has length 2 so the basic idea is:

- First create an array of length **n+1** with all values fill with **0**.
- Second, where you try to match the pattern `AC` in the string **s** So mark **1** at the index of `C` in **arr** when you match `AC` in the string.
- By This you will be iterating the array only once before answering any query
- For each Query you can solve this in **O(1)** time, since the total patterns found will be `arr[r] - arr[l-1]`
- **Note**, Make sure you look for partial overlaps as explained in below code

Hope this helps:

```
// This program is created by Ishpreet Singh
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int n, q, l, r;
  string s;
  cin >> n >> q;
  cin >> s;
  // The lookUp Arr
  int arr[n + 1];
  arr[0] = arr[1] = 0;
  for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
  {
    if (s.at(i - 1) == 'A' && s.at(i) == 'C'){
      arr[i + 1] = arr[i] + 1;
    }
    else{
      arr[i + 1] = arr[i];
    }
  }
  while (q--)
  {
    cin >> l >> r;
    int ans = arr[r] - arr[l - 1];
    // To Remove partial overlaps of AC, like s[l-1] = 'A' and s[l] = 'C'
    if (l > 1 && arr[l] == arr[l - 1] + 1){
      ans--;
    }
    cout << ans << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

By this way you can answer the queries in **`O(1)`** time, so the overall complexity of the code will be **`O(Q)`** which will pass all the test case in 1 sec.

Comment: Why is the array size n + 1? Would it be easier if we can assign arr[0] = 0, then `arr[i] = arr[i - 1]  + 1` if `arr[i] = 'C' && arr[i] = 'A'`.

Comment: @AhZong Its because the strings are 1 indexed. Also for the case when **l** =1 `a[r]-a[l-1]` will still hold.